# How to easily randomize an array?

Tags: c#

**After my last question completely died I would like to ask a question:**

How could I EASILY implement an array randomizer into my code:

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axSkype1.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText = ();
}
```

This is my code and I'm using the skype4comlib so don't worry but I would like to find a way that I could set the users Skype 'mood' to a random element of an array such as "I am failing at coding, The Slow Brown Sheep jumped over the fox" yea oh and also I'm going to attach this to a 5 min timer but yea I can do that but not the array.

Comment: So you just want to pick a random element from an already filled array?

Comment: Thankyou all so much stackoverflow has a really good community that i am not very used to yet but i know that they are willing to help so thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void button9_Click()
    {
        string messages = "I am failing at coding,The Slow Brown Sheep jumped over the fox,Message3,Message4, Message5";
        string[] messagesArray = messages.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        axSkype1.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText =messagesArray[new Random().Next(0,messagesArray.Length)].ToString();
    }
```

or you can use a method to return a random string form a "messages" string:

```
    private void button9_Click()
    {
        string messages = "I am failing at coding,The Slow Brown Sheep jumped over the fox,Message3,Message4,Message5";
        axSkype1.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText =GetRandomMessage(messages);
    }

    string GetRandomMessage(string messages)
    {
        string[] messagesArray = messages.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        return messagesArray[new Random().Next(0, messagesArray.Length)].ToString();
    }
```

or

Answer (score 1):

You can use as an index of the array the following expression: `new Random().Next(0,SIZE_OF_YOUR_ARRAY)`

So if your array is called `MoodTexts` you can use something like that:

`String randomText = MoodTexts[new Random().Next(0,MoodTexts.Length)];`

Answer (score 0):

Create a private member as an instance of the Random class.

```
var random = new Random ();
```

Then use it to get a new random number whenever you need one.

```
random.Next(0, messagesArray.Length)
```

This will give you back a random number between 0 and the length of your array minus 1, which you can use to randomly index into the array.

Creating the single instance of the Random class is important.  If you recreate the Random class over and over,  the randomness of the values may not be as random as you'd like.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx